# Offset UIScrollView from a child ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, parentviewcontroller

I currently have an application with a UI Similar to the Snapchat ScrollView. The MainViewController contains a UIScroll, in which three child ViewControllers are added as child ViewControllers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.bounds.width*3 + 4), self.view.bounds.height)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    scrollView.addSubview(view1)
    let aVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("One")
    view1.addSubview(aVC!.view)
    self.addChildViewController(aVC!)

    let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.width), 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    scrollView.addSubview(view2)
    let bVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Two")
    view2.addSubview(bVC!.view)
    self.addChildViewController(bVC!)

    let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(2*view.bounds.width), 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height))
    scrollView.addSubview(view3)
    let cVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationViewController")
    view3.addSubview(cVC!.view)
    self.addChildViewController(cVC!)

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width, 0
    }
```

I attempting to add buttons two the middle ViewController, which will offset the ScrollView to either the left or right View Controllers. I know I can use setContentOffset() in the MainViewController, but I cannot call this in the child view controllers. Both self.presentingViewController and self.parentViewController both return nil.

What is the best way to call setContentOffset() for the UIScrollView, within a child ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). Add a delegate to the ViewControllers with views that will change, then have your parent ViewController get itself as the delegate. Then you can inspect the views and resize accordingly.